# Query regarding spark ingestion. [Java]

Tags: java, apache-spark

I need suggestion on below query .

We have huge number of zip files stored in Amazon S3.

Zip file name pattern is prefix_timestamp.

Same name zipEntry can only be present in zip files with the same prefix.

One way to process data is to create newAPIHadoopFile like below.

Here JavaPairRDD key is zipentry filename and value is content of the file[zipEntry file].

```
List<String> s3Keys = getS3Keys(); // list of s3 path to zip files

JavaPairRDD<Text, BytesWritable>  rddZipEntryFileNameToFile = sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(String.join(",", s3Keys), ZipFileInputFormat.class, Text.class, BytesWritable.class, sparkConfig);
```

..

..

```
rddZipEntryFileNameToProcessedData
```

I need to apply reduceByKey to the processed result, since same name zipEntry can be there in multiple zip files.This gives me the desired result.

Ex:

```
//key is zipEntry file name
rddZipEntryFileNameToProcessedData.reduceByKey((v1, v2) -> {

                        v1.mergeValue(v2);
                        return v1;
                    })
```

For performance reason i am looking for some solution to avoid reduceByKey and 
either process same name zip entry file in single host or partition.

Ex : `JavaPairRDD<Text, Lis<BytesWritable> >  rddZipEntryFileNameToFiles`

Or if I can process zip files with same prefix on one host.

Basically i want to take advantage of the fact that zipEntry with same name can be part of zip files with same prefix.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`reduceByKey` is efficient. It will processing that in the same node as long as it is possible , i.e if spark assigns that partition to that node.